# Why do constructors seem to allocate memory for the same object multiple times?

Tags: delphi, oop, constructor

Apparently, I don't understand how constructors work.

When my application starts, it automatically or when needed executes my procedure that loads all resources - mostly images.

```
procedure Load;
begin
  AppPath := GetAppPath;
  INI := TInIFile.Create(AppPath + '\Config.ini');
  INI.WriteBool('Application', 'Running', True);
  ResPath := AppPath + '\Resources';
  Top := TPicture.Create;
  TopRight := TPicture.Create;
  Left := TPicture.Create;
  Right := TPicture.Create;
  BottomLeft := TPicture.Create;
  Bottom := TPicture.Create;
  BottomRight := TPicture.Create;

  ...

  //Load the pictures ...LoadFromFile(Skin.ReadString('Skin', ..., ...));
```

While I was using this application it started to lag a bit, but the OS started to freeze and lag too. I was shocked when I saw my program in Task Manager:

[image: MEM]

If I'm right, the application used 600 megs of RAM with page file included. My system has only 1 GB of RAM, so it's no wonder the OS and almost every program started to lag due the page file usage.

Turned out it was that same procedure that loaded the resources every time I did something. I fixed it with adding a boolean to unit and the procedure canceled when it was set to true (means the resources are loaded).

```
Loaded: Boolean;
...
if Loaded = False then Load;
```

I'm not understanding why I had to make that change at all. Why did the constructor allocate memory for already-created objects in the first place?

Comment: The question will possibly be closed as `not a real question` if you will not show the code of your 'Constructor'.

Comment: Question is impossible to answer. A plain app doesn't do this so it must be something particular about your app. But we can't guess what it is so you'd need to show enough code for us to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: I can't relate "a procedure getting called repeatedly when it shouldn't" with constructors.

Comment: Well, this clearly is a procedure, not a constructor. The solution for your problem has to be found behind the _when needed_ because obviously you're calling this routine more then once.

Comment: I hope my edits make your question more readable. You are wondering why code that you call twice executes twice.  Ask yourself what would the use of Delphi be, if you could not create an object more than once, or you could never call code again, intentionally, with the second call doing all the same work that the first one did, if you so desire?

Comment: LOL @ `if Loaded = False then`

Comment: how about the yodaConditional version?  if False = Loaded then ... :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan GetAppPath gets application direcotry

Comment: You're app cannot work if installed in Program Files then due to that folder being read only to standard users. You should store these settings under the per-user profile I expect.

Comment: @WarrenP: How about the cleaner code way? `if not Loaded then` Roberts, those are extremely poorly chosen variable names if they're real. The vars `Top` and `Left` conflict with properties of almost any other `TWinControl`, and can cause hard to track down bugs (especially when you're in a form's method handler and refer to `Top` expecting your image to change and instead it's the form's `Top` that's altered (or vice versa). Worse yet is if you use the dreaded `with` statement in an event handler or something, where you can end up accidentally messing things up badly because of scoping issues.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree, but those variables are in other unit called `MainUnit` and to call `Top` I just use `MainUnit.Top...` get it?

Comment: @WarrenP I understand, but Im from different country and it's hard to give each object it's own name very quickly.

Comment: Okay. Well your sample code problem is not the name, but the fact that you said "function X" instead of "function TSomething.X". You understand the difference right?  And unit 1 and unit 2 are not your only "scopes". There are object scopes too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was about to say something about `GetAppPath` - why not use `Application.ExeName`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Constructors only allocate memory when the object doesn't already exist. If the constructor is called on an existing object, then that object is constructed; a new one is not allocated. (What you decide to do *inside* the constructor is another matter. Those instructions might allocate more memory in addition to whatever the `InstanceSize` function returns for the class.)

Your code doesn't show any constructors being called on existing objects, though. You're calling constructors on *classes*, and that allocates a new instance of each class. For example, you construct an INI-file object:

```
INI := TInIFile.Create(AppPath + '\Config.ini');
```

That calls the constructor on `TIniFile`. It allocates a new `TIniFile` instance and initializes it. Once that is finished, a reference to that new object is stored in the `INI` variable. Important to realize is that if `INI` already held a reference to some *other* object, that reference is discarded and the new one is stored in `INI` instead. You're not calling the `TIniFile` constructor on the object that's already referenced by `INI`. That object is completely independent of the new one being created.

The `INI` variable isn't a `TIniFile` object. It's a *reference* to an object.

You are apparently calling your `Load` function multiple times. Each time you call it, you re-run all the object constructors you ran before. You have a memory leak because each time you construct a new set of objects, you store references to them in the same variables you already stored the previous object references in. The previous values are discarded, and there's no way to get them back, so there's no way to free them. The way to solve this is as you've shown: Make sure you only initialize your program once by keeping track of whether you've already loaded.

Comment: +1 This is one exact reason why I don't put this type of initialization in a separate procedure if I have the ability to put it directly in the constructor. There's no reason for it to be anywhere else.